# "FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions" when creating document in Google Firestore as authenticated user

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a document in Google Firestore as follows:

```
    const docData = {
      name: name,
      type: type,
      ownerId: this.auth.session!.userUid
    }

    await addDoc(collection(this.firebase.firestore, "projects"), docData)
```

I can see (via an `onAuthStateChanged(...)` callback), that the user is signed-in and making an authenticated request. The payload is `{ name: "dfgdfgdfg", type: "CommonV1", ownerId: "5sp...F53" }` (ellipses added for brevity; the full `ownerId` is given in the actual request). However, I receive an "FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions." error.

I would like `projects` to be accessible to the user who created them, and nobody else (to begin with). To this end, my security rules are as follows:

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // True if the user is signed in and they own the resource.
    function OwnsResource() {
      return request.auth.uid != null && resource.data.ownerId == request.auth.uid;
    }

    // By default, no documents may be read.
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
    
    // Allow a project to be created, read or written by its owner.
    match /projects/{project} {
      allow create, read, write: if ownsResource();
    }
  }
}
```

I believe the problem is in my rules, but I cannot see where.

How can I resolve this problem and create the project, as desired?

Comment: `OwnsResource` and `ownsResource` are not the same

Comment: Good eyes @phil. I've updated the code and am still seeing the same error.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to match. Did you deploy your rule changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring that `allow create` is redundant with `allow write`: `resource.data` points to the data in your document as it was when you made the change. So for a document that does not yet exist, this will be `null`. You then call `null.ownerId`, which throws an exception and blocks the change.

To prevent throwing the exception, you'd need to check for this first:

```js
function OwnsResource() {
  return request.auth != null && resource.data != null && resource.data.ownerId == request.auth.uid;
}
```

However, this rule won't handle a newly created document (as `resource.data` will be `null`), you'd need to either add to the above function, or create a new one:

```js
function OwnsCreatedResource() {
  return request.auth != null && resource.data == null && request.resource.data.ownerId == request.auth.uid;
}
```

It is important to note that in the above rules that the prior state of the document is checked. By using just `request.resource.data.ownerId` over `resource.data.ownerId`, the **new write can change the old `ownerId` of the document**. So `userB` could take over `userA`'s project.

Additionally, note that `request.auth.uid != null` has been corrected to `request.auth != null`. The former statement will throw an exception when a user is not logged in.

This then allows your rules to become:

```
// Allow a project to be created, read or written by its owner.
match /projects/{project} {
  allow read, write: if ownsResource() || ownsCreatedResource();
}
```

or

```
// Allow a project to be created, read or written by its owner.
match /projects/{project} {
  allow read, update, delete: if ownsResource();
  allow create: if ownsCreatedResource();
}
```

Comment: Awesome answer, well deserved "accepted".

Answer (score 0):

I was pointed to the firebase rules editor in the Firebase console. It helped me identify an error (in addition to Phil's comment). Where I had:

```
    function OwnsResource() {
      return request.auth.uid != null && resource.data.ownerId == request.auth.uid;
    }
```

It should have had:

```
    function ownsResource() {
      return request.auth.uid != null && request.resource.data.ownerId == request.auth.uid;
    }
```

This works. For anyone reading this: the Firestore rules playground in the Firebase console is an excellent tool.

Comment: This has a severe security issue where a project's owner can be overwritten as you only check the new `ownerId` value rather than the old `ownerId` value when it exists.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @samthecodingman :). I'm new to Firestore so just feeling my way through the basics. I appreciate the pointer and will sort that out ASAP!